# How to repeat a function multiple times in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, repeat

I would like to add new rows to my data frame multiple times, and I need the number of rows added to vary depending on the time point I've set in the loop. However, I'm at a loss for how to do this.

My current code is this:

```
timepoint <- c("Day 0", 'Day 1', 'Day 2')
for (i in timepoint)
{
additional_counts <- df1[df1$Time == i,]
cluster_participants <-  length(unique(IgH_CDR3_cluster_count_combined$ID))
total_participants <- nrow(unique(select(filter(IgH_CDR3_cluster, Time== i), ID)))
repeats <- as.numeric(total_participants - cluster_participants)
action <- function(x){ df1 %>% add_row(Time = i, count = 0)}
}
```

I'd like to perform the action n=repeats times on data frame: additional_counts. The result of repeats is a numeric value that will change depending on the timepoint, so you can just put any number there. The number of repeats doesn't really matter, I just want to be able to carry out a function n=repeats many times, and so any value can be assigned to 'repeats'.

Here is df1 :

```
structure(list(time = c("Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", 
"Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 0", "Day 1", "Day 1", 
"Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", "Day 1", 
"Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", 
"Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", 
"Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", 
"Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2", "Day 2"), count = c(1L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 59L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 54L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 207L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 11L, 2L, 1L), cluster = c("C", 
"C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "A", "A", "D", "D", 
"D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "B", "C", 
"B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A")), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Adding rows one (or a few) at a time is terribly inefficient. It's much better to add all the rows at once, or add a bunch of blank rows and fill them in.

Comment: How would I do this?

Comment: What's the output you want? I can't tell how exactly the timepoint affects what you add to the data frame

Comment: You can ignore timepoint really. All I need to be able to do is carry out the action n=repeats many times, and the value of repeats will change depending on the time point. The actual value isn't important right now, so random numbers can be used.

Comment: try a while loop. `while the number you want repeated is greater than 0 {function(); decrement n}`

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361434/r-for-loop-n-times https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52718776/repeat-loop-upto-certain-number-of-times-in-r https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55812476/r-repeat-operation-n-times-and-store-in-vector

Comment: The loop has some variables, which have not been defined in the code, so it is difficult to understand your goal: `IgH_CDR3_cluster_count_combined` and `IgH_CDR3_cluster`.